# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar una fila de una matriz? JAVA

Tags: java, matrices, netbeans-8.2

estoy haciendo un ejercicio donde necesito eliminar una fila de una matriz/arreglo bidimensional a decisión del usuario pero no encuentro la forma de hacer que se elimine.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Inicialización de variables
    int[][] matriz = new int [4][4];
    String decision;
    int filaQuitar;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Inicialización de la matriz 4x4 con números aleatorios del 1 al 9
    for (int filas = 0; filas < 4; filas++) {
        System.out.println("");
        for (int columnas = 0; columnas < 4; columnas++) {
            matriz[filas][columnas] = (int) (Math.random() *9+1);
            System.out.print(matriz[filas][columnas] + "\t");
        }
    }

    System.out.println(\n¿Desea eliminar alguna fila?");
    decision= input.nextLine();

    switch(decision){
        case "si":
            System.out.println("¿Cuál fila desea eliminar?: ");
            filaQuitar= input.nextInt();

            for (int filas = 0; filas < 4; filas++) {
                for (int columnas = 0; columnas < 4; columnas++) {
                    if (filas == filaQuitar) {
                        filas.remove(filas);
                    }
                }
            }

            //Imprimir la nueva matriz sin la fila elegida
            System.out.println("Nueva Matriz");
            for (int filas = 0; filas < 4; filas++) {
                System.out.println();
                for (int columnas = 0; columnas < 4; columnas++) {
                    System.out.print(matriz[filas][columnas] + "\t");
                }
            }
            break;
    }//termina el switch

}//main
```

Quiero recorrer de nuevo toda la matriz y puntualizar que cuando las filas sean iguales que la decisión que tomó el usuario, es decir, cuando la fila sea igual a la fila que el usuario quiera eliminar, entonces eliminar completamente dicha fila, pero tengo dudas al hacerlo.

Utilicé `filas.remove(filas);` para eliminar las filas elegidas pero no funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos por partes.

```
for (int filas = 0; filas < 4; filas++) {
            for (int columnas = 0; columnas < 4; columnas++) {
                if (filas == filaQuitar) {
                    filas.remove(filas);
                }
            }
        }
```

En este loop anidado tu estas definiendo la variable "filas" como el entero que te va a permitir iterar en el arreglo.

El metodo .remove es un metodo de la clase ArrayList que se utiliza para eliminar objetos en una lista dinamica en base a una posicion enviada por parametro. asi que la siguiente sentencia no tiene sentido.

```
filas.remove(filas);
```

Tienes que tener en cuenta que un arreglo primitivo (como lo estas definiendo) es estatico y no puedes "eliminar" posiciones dentro de el (por eso debes definir la cantidad de posiciones al crearlo).

Lo que si puedes hacer es recorrer todo el arreglo y establecer todos los valores de una determinada fila en '0', por poner un ejemplo.

Eso se lograria con el siguiente codigo:

```
System.out.println("¿Cuál fila desea eliminar?: ");
            filaQuitar= input.nextInt();
            for (int filas = 0; filas < 4; filas++) {
                for (int columnas = 0; columnas < 4; columnas++) {
                    if (filas == filaQuitar) {
                        matris[filas][columnas]=0;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Ahora, si lo que necesitas es eliminar una fila en especifico deberias utilizar un arreglo de tipo ArrayList (y en este caso en especifico, de dos dimensiones).

Para eso basicamente deberias tener un ArrayList en donde cada posicion contenga a otro ArrayList, y cuando quieras eliminar una fila en especifico solo deberias utilizar el metodo ".remove(p)" en donde p es la posicion de la fila, sin necesidad de loopear.

Answer (score 0):

No puedes cambiar la dimensión de un array estático. La solución pasa por crear una nueva matriz, con la matriz que ya tienes creada y en base al indice que quieres eliminar, hacer un if dentro de la creación para no añadirla. En el método, debes hacer diferentes comprobaciones(que la fila exista, que la fila esté dentro del rango de la matriz, que la matriz esté inicializada, etc).

```
function int[][] quitarFilas(int[][] matriz, int n_fila){

        int filaInsertar = 0;
        int[][] nuevaMatriz = new int[matriz.length-1][matriz[0].length];

        for(int i=0; i < matriz.length; i++){             
            if(i != n_fila){
               for(int j=0; j<matriz[i].length; j++){                
                    nuevaMatriz[i][j] = matriz[n_fila][j];                    
               }
             n_fila++;               
            }              
        }
    }
    return nuevaMatriz; 
}
```

Si lo que quieres es eliminar una columna, puedes echar un vistazo aqui:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40799356/how-to-delete-2d-array-column-in-java