# Remover una fila de un arreglo bidimensional (matriz) JAVA

Tags: java, matrices, netbeans-8.2

estoy haciendo un ejercicio donde el usuario eligirá la fila que desea remover del arreglo bidimensional o matriz. Estoy teniendo un problema para encontrar la forma cómo hacerlo.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Inicialización de variables
    int[][] matriz = new int[4][4];
    String decision;
    int filaQuitar;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Inicialización de la matriz 4x4 con números aleatorios del 1 al 9
    for (int filas = 0; filas < 4; filas++) {
        System.out.println("");
        for (int columnas = 0; columnas < 4; columnas++) {
            matriz[filas][columnas] = (int) (Math.random() * 9 + 1);
            System.out.print(matriz[filas][columnas] + "\t");
        }
    }

    System.out.println("\n¿Desea eliminar alguna fila?");
    decision = input.nextLine();

    switch (decision) {
        case "si":

            System.out.println("¿Cuál fila desea eliminar?: ");
            filaQuitar = input.nextInt();

            //Copio los valores de la matriz original a la nueva matriz
            int nuevaMatriz [][] = new int[matriz.length-1][matriz[0].length];
            for (int filas = 0; filas < matriz.length-1 ; filas++) {
                for (int columnas = 0; columnas < matriz[0].length; columnas++) {
                    nuevaMatriz[filas][columnas]= matriz[filas][columnas];
                }
            }

            //Imprimir la nueva matriz sin la fila elegida
            System.out.println("Nueva Matriz");
            for (int filas = 0; filas < 4; filas++) {
                System.out.println();
                for (int columnas = 0; columnas < 4; columnas++) {
                    System.out.print(nuevaMatriz[filas][columnas] + "\t");
                }
            }
            break;         
    }//termina el switch
}//main
```

Estoy intentando hacer una nueva matriz copiando los valores de la matriz original pero quiero que se exceptue la fila que eligirá el usuario para eliminar, es decir, quiero que la matriz nueva sea exactamente la misma que la otra pero que no se copie la fila en cuestión que el usuario eligió.

```
int nuevaMatriz [][] = new int[matriz.length-1][matriz[0].length];
            for (int filas = 0; filas < matriz.length-1 ; filas++) {
                for (int columnas = 0; columnas < matriz[0].length; columnas++) {
                    nuevaMatriz[filas][columnas]= matriz[filas][columnas];
                }
            }
```

En esta parte del código copio los valores de la matriz original a la nueva y ahí mismo debería hacer la excepción de la fila elegida.

El problema es que no sé cómo ejecutar esa excepción o cómo debería hacerla.

Comment: Y por qué repetir la misma pregunta varias veces?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo puedo eliminar una fila de una matriz? JAVA](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/359136/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-eliminar-una-fila-de-una-matriz-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes el nro. de fila a remover en la variable filaQuitar. Entonces simplemente en el for de filas, tienes que verificar que si el indice filas es igual a filaQuitar, te saltas el for de las columnas. 
Ten en cuenta que los arrays en Java comienzan en 0, pero el ingreso del dato por teclado probablemente empiece en 1, si es así, deberías restar 1 de filaQuitar antes de comenzar el loop.